# VC++ HeapAlloc inside function gives null pointer

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, malloc, heapalloc

I am trying to use `HeapAlloc()` to allocate a buffer used by `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty()`.

Inside `GetDeviceInformation()` I have:

```
HANDLE hHeap = GetProcessHeap();

while (SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(DeviceInfoSet, MemberIndex++, DeviceInfoData)) 
{
    DWORD DataT;
    LPTSTR buffer = NULL;
    DWORD buffersize = 0;
    // port of device
    DWORD portnum = 0;

    GetRegistryProperty(DeviceInfoSet, DeviceInfoData, SPDRP_FRIENDLYNAME, 
         &DataT, buffer, &buffersize, &buffersize);

    if (!buffer) 
    {
        cerr << "Null Ptr!" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    // Do stuff, uninstall device


    if (buffer) HeapFree(hHeap, NULL, buffer); 

    }
}
```

And inside `GetRegistryProperty()` I have:

```
void GetRegistryProperty(HDEVINFO DeviceInfoSet, PSP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData, 
    DWORD Property, PDWORD DataT, LPTSTR buffer, PDWORD buffersize, PDWORD size)
{


    HANDLE hHeap = GetProcessHeap();

    while (!SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(
        DeviceInfoSet,
        DeviceInfoData,
        Property, //SPDRP_FRIENDLYNAME or SPDRP_CLASS
        DataT, //&DataT
        (PBYTE)buffer,
        *buffersize,
        size)) //&buffersize
    {
        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
        {
            // Change the buffer size.
            if (buffer) HeapFree(hHeap, NULL, buffer); 

            // Double the size to avoid problems on 
            // W2k MBCS systems per KB 888609. 
            buffer = (LPTSTR)HeapAlloc(hHeap, HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY |
                HEAP_GENERATE_EXCEPTIONS, *buffersize * 2);
        }
        else
        {
            // error handling
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

`HeapAlloc()` works as expected (the buffer is filled with the property) until `GetRegistryProperty()` returns.  At this point, the buffer is always NULL.  Is this also expected?  How can I return a char * pointing to an array that lives past the life of the function that created it?  I assume that I don't understand how HeapAlloc() works.

The reason I have it in a separate function is that I would like to call `GetRegistryProperty()` multiple times with different `DWORD Property`s.  Before I moved the code to a separate function it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the `buffer` by reference (note the **LPTSTR&**) :

```
void GetRegistryProperty(HDEVINFO DeviceInfoSet, PSP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData, 
    DWORD Property, PDWORD DataT, LPTSTR& buffer, PDWORD buffersize, PDWORD size)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `buffer` by value, so in GetRegistryProperty, when you reassign it, you simply overwrite the copy of the pointer in GetRegistryProperty.

Change the signature of GetRegistryProperty to:

```
void GetRegistryProperty(HDEVINFO DeviceInfoSet, PSP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData, DWORD Property, PDWORD DataT, LPTSTR& buffer, PDWORD buffersize, PDWORD size)
```